# nagare framework on gae?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-stackless

anyone using nagare framework on google app engine ?

it seems interesting, but i could not find any documentaiton on how to use it on

google app engine, as it uses stackless python.

so any chances of its running on google app engine ?

also, how stack less python differ from normal python ?

thanks.

links :

[Nagare Framework](http://www.nagare.org/index.html)

[Stackless python](http://www.stackless.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I currently have a not-yet-released, prototype version of Nagare for GAE (you can see the canonical Counter example at http://nagareproject.appspot.com/)

Here are the 3 Nagare components not working on GAE, with their workarounds in this prototype:

- Stackless Python:

  - Problem: GAE is only pure vanilla CPython
  - Solution: well, use only pure Python
  - Limitation: in Nagare, Stackless Python is used to obtain continuation objects. Without Stackless, we lose the call()/answer() feature of Nagare. But note that call()/on_answer() is still working.
- Lxml:

  - Problem: C module not accepted on GAE
  - Solution: HTML generation rewrote using only ElementTree
  - Limitation: no more advance Lxml features like XSL or complex XPATH expressions
- PEAK-Rules:

  - Problem: standard AST tree management removed on GAE
  - Solution: rules management for HTML/JS generation rewrote
  - Limitation: the security and URL dispatch rules must be written by the developer without the help of generic methods

So, this version of Nagare is pretty much working fine on GAE. And I dare to say that, even with these limitations, Nagare still stay on GAE a better programming environement than the others Python frameworks.

If you want to test it, send a message in the Nagare users group or send me a personal mail to alain.poirier at net-ng.com

Comment: nagare is superb, i would like to try on app engine. It will be cool if you can release some code, I can help with testing and and stuffs.

Answer (score 1):

If it has a hard dependency on Stackless, it won't run on AppEngine. AE has its own Python runtime. If it doesn't leverage any of Stackless's non-standard extensions to Python, it might work, but I'd say that your chances aren't very good that it would just work.